# Matching a string against a column full of regular expressions

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, regex

I have a column in a table that is full of regular expressions.

I have a string in my code, and I want to find out which regular expressions in that column would match that string and return those rows.

Aside from pulling each row and matching the regular expression (which is costly, checking against potentially thousands of records for a single page load) is there a way I can do this in SQL instead with one (or a couple) queries?

Example input: W12ABC

Example column data

```
1   ^[W11][\w]+$  
2   ^[W12][\w]+$  
3   ^[W13][\w]+$ 
4   ^[W1][\w]+[A][\w]+$  
5   ^[W1][\w]+[B][\w]+$  
6   ^[W1][\w]+[C][\w]+$
```

Should return rows 2 and 4.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support RegEx *natively*. Are you open to SQL CLR? Otherwise you may have to re-write your RegEx expressions as patterns you can use with PATINDEX or LIKE. Can you show some sample data and desired results, including edge cases, so we know what you're after?

Comment: The CLR is the way to go if you can do it. But, do bear in mind that testing 'potentially thousands' of regexes for a single page load will be epically expensive whether it's a CLR function within the DB or not.

Comment: And even then, your relationship sounds backwards - unless the DB engine has some sort of special indexing for how it would process some sort of 'regex' column, you're stuck running against every row.  If that column is varchar, you're just plain stuck.

Comment: I would be more open to changing the regular expressions (since the design isn't implemented yet) than changing to CLR (since this is built in an existing, established large application). If I broke it down to just wildcards, would that be easier? For example, matching the string "W12ABC" against "W12*" or "W*ABC".

Comment: @Resorath - not easier for you, but certainly easier for the engine to execute. It still won't be stellar though.

Comment: Is the problem that you need to find regular expressions which the string matches, or are you using regular expressions to fulfill some other problem? Just asking...

Comment: @AndrewMorton The problem is as you see it. This table links to another table with more information inside of it (a more standard table with rows and columns of business data in it). The idea here is those standard information tables are categorized by regular expressions that the user assigns to them (e.g. one row may be defined by a couple of regex). Then, on another part of the application, a table full of data with human-readable string identifiers is matched against those regular expressions in order to pull out the categorized data. Clear as mud right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open to wildcards you can store patterns that work for LIKE syntax: "W12%" or "W%ABC".  Your query would look like this:

SELECT *
FROM Table
Where 'W12ABC' LIKE Column

Answer (score 1):

T-SQL doesn't provide this functionality, but you can enable it in SQL Server by writing a CLR function using the .NET regular expression classes. There is [a good article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx) explaining how to do it.